# Need help evaluating $ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{5 + 4\sin{\theta}} $.

Tags: complex-analysis

From Churchill and Brown's Complex Analysis I am trying to conclude:

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{5 + 4\sin{\theta}} = \frac{2\pi}{3}$$

I have tried substituting in:

$$\sin{\theta} = \frac{z + z^{-1}}{2i}$$

$$d\theta = \frac{dz}{zi}$$

To get (note $C$ is $|z| = 1$):

$$ \int_{C} \frac{\frac{dz}{zi}}{5 + 4\frac{z + z^{-1}}{2i}} $$

$$ \int_{C} \frac{dz}{5 - 2i(z + z^{-1})zi} $$

$$ \int_{C} \frac{dz}{5 + 2(z + z^{-1})z} $$

$$ \int_{C} \frac{dz}{5 + 2(z^2 + 1)} $$

$$ \int_{C} \frac{dz}{7 + 2z^2} $$

$$ \frac12 \int_{C} \frac{dz}{z^2 + \frac72}$$

But then I concluded the singularities of $\pm i\frac72$ were outside of the circle so the integral became $0$ instead of $\frac{2\pi}{3}$. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\left(5+4\left(\frac{z-z^{-1}}{2i}\right)\right)iz=2z^2+i5z-2$$

Comment: Oh, I forgot to distribute the $z$ to the $5$... :( Thanks! Sorry about that!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: So I realized my mistake and recomputed the right thing, but it should be -2 not +2. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And Happy Holidays.  -Mark